# Module federation in angular ready for production?

Tags: angular, angular-module-federation

I'm still learning about module federation angular in my office work. Is module federation in angular ready for production level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what you consider to be production level.

If the question, can you deploy an application with Module Federation?
Then the answer is yes.

The most common approach is the one defined by the [Angular Architects team](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-module-federation-in-webpack-5/) in this series of articles.
If you visite their [github](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf/README.md) you can see that working examples exist with it since Angular 12.
I have also been in teams that have successfully deployed MicroFrontends with it.

However, it always depends on what you consider to be production level.

From my experience with it, the technology works quite well, the main issues are on the deploy side of things.
The deploy of an application is usually done by a DevOps teams. They know how to deploy a normal application since. However, deploying Micro-Frontends is quite different which may cause additional difficulties.

Comment: Okaay, Thanks for your information about that concept. I just want to make sure that architecture is stable to deployed on production.